# Why save copy of function arguments register %rdx before MUL?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu-registers

I am learning how to combine assembly code with C program. Here is a short example of my program:

```
int umult_ok_asm(unsigned long x, unsigned long y, unsigned long *dest);
// x in %rdi, y in %rsi, dest in %rdx.
```

The function is to compute the product of arguments x and y and store the result in the memory location specified by arguments *dest*. As return values, they **should return 0 when the multiplication overflows**, requiring more than 64 bits to represent the true product, and 1 when it does not. Next, I give the complete code.

Part 1，Complete C code：

```
// file "c_code.c"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int umult_ok_asm(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long *);

int main(){
    unsigned long var;
    int t = umult_ok_asm(ULONG_MAX, 2, &var2);
    printf("asm: %d\n", t);
}
```

Part 2, Complete Assembly code:

```
# file "assembly_code.s"
.globl  umult_ok_asm

umult_ok_asm:
movq    %rdx, %rcx      # line 4， save copy of dest
movq    %rsi, %rax
mulq    %rdi
movq    %rax, (%rcx)    # line 7, Store product at dest
setae   %al
movzbl  %al, %eax
ret
```

my compilation command:

```
linux> gcc -o c_code.c assembly_code.s
```

They work fine and I got 0 as return value. BUT!

**But I can’t figure out why I can’t delete the 4th line of assembly code and replace the 7th line with** `movq   %rax, (%rdx)`. My modified Example：

```
# file "assembly_code.s"
.globl  umult_ok_asm

umult_ok_asm:
# movq    %rdx, %rcx      # Deleted code line 4
movq    %rsi, %rax
mulq    %rdi
# movq  %rax, (%rcx)     # Deleted code line 7
movq    %rax, (%rdx)     # Inserted new code, use (%rdx) store product.
setae   %al
movzbl  %al, %eax
ret
```

The above code will cause compilation errors：

```
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
（gdb）Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
```

Why I can't store product directly at dest (%rdx)?
I have to do copy dest(%rdx) to dest(%rcx)? Is there any special reason?

My code reference source：
http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/3e/waside/waside-embedded-asm.pdf

Comment: You're using `mul` (to get flags set according to unsigned, not signed, overflow of the low half).  But `mul` only has a widening form that actually writes the high half to RDX.  Otherwise you'd just use `imul %rdi, %rsi` instead of copying either operand.  If the function took the pointer arg first, you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mul: Unsigned multiply (`RDX:RAX ← RAX ∗ r/m64`).  See that about RDX?

Comment: Thanks to @Peter Cordes. I figured it out now. With the ```mulq``` instruction, the other argument to the multiplication must be in register %rax, and the product is sotred in registers %rdx (high-order 8 bytes) and %rax (low-order 8 bytes).